# What models and fields do I need to handle subscriptions such as Apple's Autorenewable Subscriptions?

Tags: django, database, model, app-store, subscription

I want to build an autorenewable subscription service, with an introductory trial period. There doesn't seem to be much written documentation on what models and fields I need to best model (and futureproof) my subscriptions. I'm starting with Apple's App store right now, but I do have a web interface and want to go to the Play Store at some point.

From this video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/705/ it seems like the minimum I need is something like a `Subscription` model with fields `userId, productId, originalTransactionId, latestExpiresDate, consumedProductDiscounts, latestReceiptData`.

Is there anything else I need?

Will I be able to properly retrieve other subscription information in the future and augment my table (i.e. the `billingRetry` information as suggested in the video for grace periods; my understanding is by sending the saved receipt data I can get the JSON blob again and retrieve additional fields if I need to)?

Is this extensible to co-exist with web and Play Store subscriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These is the models we use to handle the subscription. maybe it helps you.

```
struct BillingTransaction : Codable {
    var expires_date: String
    var original_purchase_date: String
    var is_in_intro_offer_period: Bool
    var product_id: String
    var original_transaction_id: Int
    var transaction_id: Int
}

struct BillingReceipt : Codable {
    var app_item_id: String
    var application_version: String
    var bundle_id: String
    var in_app: [BillingTransaction]
}

struct BillingRenewalInfo : Codable {
    var product_id: String
    var auto_renew_product_id: String
    var auto_renew_status: Int
    var is_in_billing_retry_period: Int
    var original_transaction_id: Int
}
```

Comment: Which models are associated with the user?

Comment: The model  BillingReceipt is associate with the user, but Apple doesn't give anything about the user, you have to already has his email or something to identify it beforehand